# Running ng e2e removes dist folder and doesn't look for the compiled .js files

Tags: protractor, jasmine2.0

I am trying to run ng e2e to run my protractor tests. My compiled .js files are saved in 'dist' folder. However, whenever I run 'ng e2e', I observed that my dist folder is removed and the result of ng e2e is no specs found since the compiled files that are in 'dist' folder are removed when i run ng e2e.

Also, my protractor.conf.js file contains plugins related to 'jasmine2-protractor-utils' and 'protractor-html-reporter. So, when I run 'ng e2e', it says no modules found for 'jasmine2-protractor-utils'.

All my above tests work fine when I run them directly using 'protractor conf.js' command. Can you please advise on how to achieve the same result with 'ng e2e' so that it can be used while doing the environment builds.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To stop `ng e2e` from removing your `/dist` directory run

`ng e2e --delete-output-path=false`

To learn more Angular CLI command line arguments run

`ng help`